# mod_proxy with jira war installation

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, tomcat5.5, jira

So I have jira installed and I access i through mydomain.com:8080/jira.  I'd really like to access i through jira.mydomain.com.  I enabled mod_proxy and put the following in an apache vhost:

```
ServerName jira.mydomain.com

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/jira
```

But, it forwards me to jira.mydomain.com/jira.  Which doesn't work.  I changed the base URL in jira to jira.mydomain.com also.  What's going on here, why does the extra /jira exist?

I installed jira as a war installation as I'm running other apps through tomcat (confluence, hudson etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radius you were so close, apparently i need a trailing / after the proxypass directives, so:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/jira/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/jira/
```

Worked like a charm.  I then needed to add a re-write so all the static images/css etc would be mapped:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule       ^/jira(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/jira$1 [P,L]
```

Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/jira
```

Comment: Still didn't work.  Could this be a tomcat issue, where it always forwards to the context path?  This is my first tomcat install with an attempt to proxy through apache so I don't know much about this.  I tried changing the context path to just / in my jira.xml file, to no avail.

Comment: Don't know Tomcat enough to answer. But you probably need to change something in some tomcat .xml configuration file where JIRA application is defined.